# Docker Compose Environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml is looked like this below.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  identity.api:
    image: panda/identity.api
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Identity/PandaMarket.Identity.Api/Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionString=Server=sql.server;Database=PandaMarket.Identity;User Id=sa;Password=Password#123
```

When I perform docker-compose build or docker-compose up

I check `docker inspect panda/identity.api`, I can't find the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT & ConnectionString is appear.

When i perform

```
docker inspect -f '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}} {{$value}} {{end}}' panda/identity.api
```

I only able to see these variables

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80  DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true  ASPNETCORE_VERSION=2.1.2
```

My question is how the environment is reflected in the images?

Comment: This are environment variables which will be added to your running container. They aren't known inside the image. You will see them when you inspect your container instead of the image. If you want to put this environment variables inside your image you need to write a Dockerfile and add the ENV statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want environment variables to be defined inside your image, you need to define them inside the Dockerfile. You can pass a build arg to allow you to change that environment variable from the compose file.

The environment variables, and other settings like command and entrypoint, when set in the compose file, apply to the running containers. You will need to run `docker-compose up` or `docker stack deploy ...` to see the results of these settings.

Note that builds are starting to be discouraged from being run from compose. They are no longer a feature of the version 3 format, and do not apply when you use a compose file to deploy with an orchestration tool like swarm mode. The ideal solution is to build with a CI server that pushes to a registry.